# Async Spring Batch job fails to process file

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to process a file, and upload it into a database, using spring batch, right after uploading it. However the job completes right after it's started, and I'm not too sure of the exact reason. I think it's not doing what it should, in the tasklet.execute. Below is the DEBUG output:

```
22:25:09.823 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.a.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource - Initializing lazy target object
22:25:09.912 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=moneyTransactionImport]] launched with the following parameters: [{targetFile=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.1435325122308787143.8080\uploads\test.csv}]
22:25:09.912 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Job execution starting: JobExecution: id=95, version=0, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Tue Sep 16 22:25:09 BST 2014, status=STARTING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=52, version=0, Job=[transactionImport]], jobParameters=[{targetFile=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.1435325122308787143.8080\uploads\test.csv}]
22:25:09.971 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Resuming state=transactionImport.step with status=UNKNOWN
22:25:09.972 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Handling state=transactionImport.step
22:25:10.018 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [step]
22:25:10.019 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Executing: id=93
22:25:10.072 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.scope.StepScope - Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.reader
22:25:10.117 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.scope.StepScope - Registered destruction callback in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.reader
22:25:10.136 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  o.s.b.item.file.FlatFileItemReader - Input resource does not exist class path resource [C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Temp/tomcat.1435325122308787143.8080/uploads/test.csv]
22:25:10.180 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Starting repeat context.
22:25:10.181 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat operation about to start at count=1
22:25:10.181 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.c.StepContextRepeatCallback - Preparing chunk execution for StepContext: org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext@5d85b879
22:25:10.181 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.c.StepContextRepeatCallback - Chunk execution starting: queue size=0
22:25:12.333 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Starting repeat context.
22:25:12.333 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat operation about to start at count=1
22:25:12.334 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
22:25:12.334 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet - Inputs not busy, ended: true
22:25:12.334 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
22:25:12.337 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=93, version=1, name=step, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
22:25:12.358 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
22:25:12.358 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step execution success: id=93
22:25:12.419 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=93, version=3, name=step, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
22:25:12.442 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=transactionImport.step with status=COMPLETED
22:25:12.443 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Handling state=transactionImport.COMPLETED
22:25:12.443 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=transactionImport.COMPLETED with status=COMPLETED
22:25:12.445 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=95, version=1, startTime=Tue Sep 16 22:25:09 BST 2014, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Tue Sep 16 22:25:09 BST 2014, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=52, version=0, Job=[transactionImport]], jobParameters=[{targetFile=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.1435325122308787143.8080\uploads\test.csv}]
22:25:12.466 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=transactionImport]] completed with the following parameters: [{targetFile=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.1435325122308787143.8080\uploads\test.csv}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

My config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
    @Inject
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<MoneyTransaction> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[targetFile]}") String file) {
        FlatFileItemReader<MoneyTransaction> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(file));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<MoneyTransaction>() {
                                 {
                                     setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                                                          {
                                                              setNames(new String[]{"Number", "Date", "Account", "Payee", "Cleared", "Amount", "Category", "Subcategory", "Memo"});

                                                          }
                                                      }
                                     );
                                     setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MoneyTransaction>() {
                                         {
                                             setTargetType(MoneyTransaction.class);

                                         }
                                     });
                                 }
                             }
        );
        reader.setStrict(false);
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<MoneyTransaction, Transaction> processor() {
        return new TransactionProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter writer() {
        RepositoryItemWriter writer = new RepositoryItemWriter();
        writer.setRepository(transactionRepository);
        writer.setMethodName("save");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<MoneyTransaction> reader,
                     ItemWriter<Transaction> writer, ItemProcessor<MoneyTransaction, Transaction> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<MoneyTransaction, Transaction>chunk(100)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        executor.setConcurrencyLimit(1);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}
```

And I save the file, and start processing in the following way:

```
public JobExecution processFile(String name, MultipartFile file) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File uploadDirectory = new File(rootPath.concat(File.separator).concat("uploads"));
                if (!uploadDirectory.exists()) {
                    uploadDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
                File uploadFile = new File(uploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(uploadFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return startImportJob(uploadFile, "transactionImport");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(String.format("Error processing file '%s'.", name), e);
                throw new MoneyException(e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new MoneyException("There was no file to process.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param file
     */
    private JobExecution startImportJob(File file, String jobName) {
        logger.debug(String.format("Starting job to import file '%s'.", file));
        try {
            Job job = jobs.get(jobName).incrementer(new MoneyRunIdIncrementer()).flow(step).end().build();
            return jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addString("targetFile", file.getAbsolutePath()).toJobParameters());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Job for processing file '%s' is already running.", file), e);
            throw new MoneyException(e);
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Invalid parameters for processing of file '%s'.", file), e);
            throw new MoneyException(e);
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Error restarting job, for processing file '%s'.", file), e);
            throw new MoneyException(e);
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Job to process file '%s' has already completed.", file), e);
            throw new MoneyException(e);
        }
    }
```

I'm kind of stumped at the minute, and any help would be greatly received.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you set strict on the `FlatFileItemReader` to true (the default)?  I'm wondering if it's finding the file...

Comment: Hi Michael, I verified that the file was uploaded correctly. However, I did comment out the reader.setStrict(false) anyway, but the same problem occurs. It's strange.

Comment: Actually, you may be onto something Michael. Although the file exists in the relevant directory, it's not picking it up. For some reason I didn't get the error when I initially commented out the reader.setStrict(false). I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The problem was with the type of resource ClassPathResource(file), combined with the fact that I was setting the strict property to false.

```
reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(file));
```

I should have used

```
reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
```

Which makes complete sense, as I wasn't uploading the file as a class path resource.